# calculate Kinect skeleton knee and elbow angles using existing joint angles

Tags: c#, kinect, angle

I'm working on a project to map Kinect captured joint data to a robot. I need to calculate the angle of the elbow and the knee. 
take the left knee for example, I get the hip-knee, and knee-angle vectors, and tried to calculate the angle between the two vectors. 
the code is below

```
Vector3D KL = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeLeft].Position.Z);
        Vector3D KR = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.KneeRight].Position.Z);

        Vector3D HL = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipLeft].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipLeft].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipLeft].Position.Z);
        Vector3D HR = new Vector3D(skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipRight].Position.X, skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipRight].Position.Y, skeleton.Joints[JointType.HipRight].Position.Z);

        //caculte knee angle
        Vector3D AKL = Vector3D.Subtract(AL, KL);
        Vector3D KHL = Vector3D.Subtract(KL, HL);

        double LAngAK_KH = Vector3D.AngleBetween(AKL, KHL);
```

the angle coming out should be around 180 for a normal standing posture. However, the output is always around 15. 
I double checked the algorithm and coding and very confused. 
Appreciated for any advice.

Comment: what are you doing in AngleBetween(AKL,KHL) function if you provide me the code of it I can better tell what's wrong you should be calculating angle between the 2 vectors using this formula cos0=(U.V)/|U|.|V| where U and V are 3D vectors to better understand check the link
https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be:

```
Vector3D AKL = Vector3D.Subtract(AL, KL);
```

AL doesn't exist in the code you copied.
 do you mean HR?